# Firmware Password isn't the one I entered

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, efi

So the firmware password isn't the one I entered. To avoid the usual onslaught of insinuations that it 'might not be my computer' that usually accompany questions of this nature, I want to state unequivocally that I am not asking how to bypass it, I'm trying to figure out why, and what (if anything) I can do to restore the EFI so that the password I entered will work. It may seem like a fine distinction, but it's an important one.

The nearest I've been able to ascertain is that the firmware I'm running is not the right firmware for my machine/OS combination. I was looking through the list of firmware updates on the Apple website here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518 and it seems that I'm running a version that isn't listed. According to the site the version for my machine should be: `MBP112.0138.B16` When I look at the system information is says that I am running `MBP112.0138.B18`

Could that be the issue? If I flash the older firmware will it respect the password or will I still be out of luck?

EDIT:

So in my haste I overlooked the disclaimer on the Apple EFI/SMC Updates page stating "If you don't see a firmware version listed in this article, it means that either a firmware update is only available as an automatic update, or no firmware update is needed."

That answers the question.

Comment: Pardon the obvious questions, but I take nothing for granted. Have you tried entering your password with an external keyboard? And is any part of your password likely to be affected by modifier keys, keyboard layout, etc?

Comment: I haven't, but will try it. There's no Unicode. All ascii, of sufficient length and complexity, entered very, very carefully. :)

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but you're aware Apple  can clear it for you, yes?

Comment: Yes... I am aware that they can clear the password for me.. In an an Apple Store.. Not presently in the US. The only apple store in this country is a days drive and I don't have the resources, So that option doesn't help me disable SIP, so that I can install tools I need for development projects in the immediate.

Comment: @Harv Can they?

Comment: @Max Ried With a receipt and an ID. Yep.

Comment: @MaxRied With proof of purchase and ID.  Typically you check your machine in for 48 hours.  They find a unique ID for the machine, send it in to Apple engineers who generate an unlock app tied to the ID but also I believe time-coded so it only works within a certain window of time.  The Apple Store rep then runs the unlock app and if everything matches up, it clears the password. I was lucky and pushed them a bit to do it then and there and it worked out fine in about 20 minutes. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203409.  Good luck!